# Alphabetically sorting output file in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

I have a program that takes data from a file:

```
Id     First Name   Last Name
1      John         Smith
2      Joe          Blow
3      Cat          Dog
```

Then takes that data and generates a username and password based on the info given above:

```
Id     Username    Password
1      SmJo1       w6o3ju2y
2      BlJo2       kv4nbu4a
3      DoCa3       7gpxlaup
```

Basically what I need done is to get my program to organize the input file in alphabetical order according to last name which would in turn organize my output file in the same order, I have no idea how to go about this though.

Comment: How are you storing the read data?. List? Array? . We need atleast some code.

Comment: Classes and custom comparators are your friends.

Comment: Each column of the file is taken and added into a seperate array, so one for ids, one for the first name, and one for the last name. Then it generates the username and password and puts those into another 2 arrays which finally leads to the output said above.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a Person class as follows:

```
public class Person {
   private int id;
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;

   public int getId() {
       return id;
   }
   public void setId(int id) {
       this.id = id;
   }
   public String getFirstName() {
       return firstName;
   }
   public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
   }
   public String getLastName() {
       return lastName;
   }
   public void setLastName(String lastName) {
       this.lastName = lastName;
   }

   public Person(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
       super();
       this.id = id;
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.lastName = lastName;
   }
}
```

you can sort the list of Person objects using the static `sort` method of Collections as shown below:

```
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
    persons.add(new Person(1, "John", "Smith"));
    persons.add(new Person(2, "Joe", "Blow"));
    persons.add(new Person(3, "Cat", "Dog"));

    Collections.sort(persons, new Comparator<Person>() {
        public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
            String lastName1 = p1.getLastName();
            String lastName2 = p2.getLastName();
            return lastName1.compareTo(lastName2);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TreeMap in this case where your key can be the lastname and value can be comma separated string of Firstname and ID or your value can be an ArrayList of string where you store the ID and Firstname as strings and later after retrieving convert them.

The treeMap will automatically store the lastname in sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Person class

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private String username;
   private String password;

  //do stuff

  public int compareTo(Person p) {
     lastName.compareTo(p.lastName);
  }

  public void writeToFile(FileWriter file) {
   //Implements
 }      

}
```

After, short the array of elements

```
Collections.sort(persons);
```

And write the persons in order

```
for (Person p : persons) {
   p.writeToFile(fileWriter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions you'll get here will probably all look fairly similar. Here's mine:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class User implements Comparable<User> {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public User(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int compareTo(User other) {
        int lastNameComparison = lastName.compareTo(other.lastName);

        return (lastNameComparison != 0 ? lastNameComparison : firstName
                .compareTo(other.firstName));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d\t%s\t%s", id, firstName, lastName);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
        users.add(new User(1, "John", "Smith"));
        users.add(new User(2, "Joe", "Blow"));
        users.add(new User(3, "Cat", "Dog"));

        Collections.sort(users);

        for(User user : users) {
            System.out.println(user.toString());
        }
    }
}
```